# AJAX Submission Form using Bottle (Python)

Tags: python, ajax, bottle

I'm having some issues getting AJAX communication working using the Bottle framework. This is my first time using AJAX, so it's likely I just have the basics wrong. Hopefully a Bottle/AJAX guru can point this novice in the right direction. Here is the code I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bottle import route, request, run, get


# Form constructor route

@route('/form')
def construct_form():
    return '''

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadXMLDoc()
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHTTPRequest();
        xmlhttp.onReadyStateChange = function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("responseDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/ajax", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }   

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <input name="username" type="text"/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="loadXMLDoc()"/>
    </form>
    <div id="responseDiv">Change this text to what you type in the box above.</div>

</body>
</html> 

    '''

# Server response generator

@route('/ajax', method='GET')
def ajaxtest():
    inputname = request.forms.username
    if inputname:
        return 'You typed %s.' % (inputname)
    return "You didn't type anything."

run(host = 'localhost', port = '8080')
```

Comment: I am testing in Chrome, so using IE-specific code isn't needed - in case anyone thinks about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1. Javascript is case sensitive.  *XMLHTTPRequest* should be *XMLHttpRequest*.  You should have seen an error about this in your Javascript console.
2. *onReadyStateChange* should be *onreadystatechange*.
3. If you fix the above two issues your AJAX call will work, but you will only ever get the 'You didn't type anything.' response.  This is because you are using GET.  You need to change your code so the form values are posted using the POST method.

Also, why aren't you using jQuery to do AJAX?  It would make your life much easier.  :)

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was going to be something simple. As for not using jQuery - I'm irritated by "magic" at this stage of my coding career, and really need to see how things are working before I'm comfortable moving on. Hence my use of Bottle (still plenty of magic here, but minimal) as well.

Comment: That's a good reason not to use jQuery (and Django).  Good luck on your Bottle project.  It's a fun framework to work with.